# Button click event is not working on Cypress, when we use vue js $emit and $on

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I have vue js application which contains the parent component and child component. I placed a button 'Submit' on parent component and it invokes api call on the child component.

Please find my source code on the parent component

```
  <button type="button" @click.prevent="buttonSubmitEvent">
            Submit
   </button>



 export default class EditModal extends Vue {
   private buttonSubmitEvent(): void {
   this.$router.app.$emit("saveEventTriggered");
    }
}
```

Please find my code on the child component

```
export default class EditHighlights extends Vue {
  private mounted() {
    this.$router.app.$on('saveEventTriggered', (data: any) => {
    this.updateHighlights();
    return;
  });
  }

  private async updateHighlights() {
    alert('api call');
  }
}
```

Also please find the source code of test file

```
import { isExportDeclaration } from "typescript";
const mountVue = require("cypress-vue-unit-test");
import camelcaseKeys from 'camelcase-keys';
import Popup from "../../../../src/components/edit/EditComponent.vue";
import { iterator } from "rxjs/internal-compatibility";
const template = `<div>
  <Popup :componentName="EditHighLightsComponent" :heading="title"></Popup>
</div>`;
const data = () => ({title:"Edit HighLights ",EditHighLightsComponent:"EditHighLightsComponent",
highlightModel: [
    {
        "Id": "31",
        "TitileOne": "mmmm  m",
        "ContentOne": "Pssoas ",
        "TitleTwo": "Rlhões22",
        "ContentTwo": "Distrbasil22",
        "TitleThree": "Pa33",
        "ContentThree": "E ada22",
        "TitleFour": "No autos25",
        "ContentFour": "Nal225",
        },], 
      })
  const components = {  Popup};
  describe('Edit highlights component ',()=>{    
  beforeEach(mountVue({ template, components,data}))

  it('check the posted data with ui',()=>{
  mountVue({ template, components,data});  
  cy.get('#btnSubmitHighlights').click();
  });
  });
```

When user clicks the ‘Submit’ button on the parent component, the method ‘updateHighlights’ should be worked. It is working on browser but not working on Cypress. Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your Cypress code and logs?

Comment: I have added the source code of the test file